# Editor for any markup language with table generation

Tags: javascript, php, editor, markup

I need some editor tools for any markup language that could provide simple table generation and text editing for my users. Something like stackoverflows markdown editor, but with table generation support. What kind of markup language and editor can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in WYSIWYG text editor called CKEditor.
It is api for web, you can embed it into your web application using just html + javascript.
It support most of major browsers, and is hightly customizable.
It generates pure html on the end. And has wide range of tools, especially the one you are looking for: table.

Check out the demo: http://ckeditor.com/demo

Comment: This is exactly what i want. But does it support any other than html output markup language? I just need to put the output text in my database, so html length isn't very good.

Comment: If you are outputting after in HTML, then this approach would be best, because table tags are pretty short: <table>, <tr>, <td>.
If you are looking for some other markup language then you might want to check out BB codes, but they are as long as html, and requires processing before output, to replace BB tags with html or any other you are using. Check out this example: http://www.bbcode.org/examples/?id=14

Comment: Upd:
here is example of plugin for CKEditor with BBCode markup: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/7460/_samples/bbcode.html editor it self is highly customizable.

Comment: Thank you! If bb-codes isn't shorter at all and as i think bb-codes CKEditor plugin doesn't support tables i would like to use html output in my database field.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like TinyMCE, but I might be biased since it's the default editor for all the projects I do at my day-job :) You can check it out here: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php but be aware, the one in the demo is set up with overkill many features enabled. It's highly customizable, so you can make it do just what you want, and pretty easily too.

Comment: This is exactly what i want to. And again, does it support any other than html output markup language? I just need to put the output text in my database, so html length isn't very good.

Comment: Supports whatever you want it to. With eZ Publish, which I daily use, it is set up to output eZ's content XML for example.